# Application permanently store variable value

Tags: c#

I am using `Properties.setting.default.var` to permanently store a value in a C# application on the same PC.

Now I am facing a problem that when I save the value but copy the application to another PC, the permanent value does not remain. Does the `properties.setting` trick not work in this scenario? If yes? Please advise the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Taha! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the settings stored in location that is accessible by all devices you plan to run your program on.

You can either

- make sure current location of the settings file is synchronized between all devices - this way you can keep your existing code. You can sync files via roaming profiles in Windows Domain, by letting some file share synchronization tool to sync that file - i.e. OneDrive, by just manually copy file or any other way you can find.
- write settings file yourself to shared location which can be accessed by all devices - pretty much any service that allow to upload data would do. Some will allow authenticated access so you can limit settings to particular user (OneDrive, GoogleDrive,...), some some form of anonymous/semi-authenticated uploads (which make personalized settings a bit harder and make them public for all to see). You may still be able to use some of the existing code but likely getting your settings in JSON format and uploading would be easier.